# redirect outside of public_html folder in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i can't redirect outside of public_html folder in htaccess file.

for example i used this code but is not working for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^framework/public/index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api$ framework/public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api/.* framework/public/index.php [L]
```

to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^../framework/public/index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^api$ ../framework/public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api/.* ../framework/public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I am confused by this. Why would one want to do that? Most likely that "public_html" folder is configured as the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of that http host. The idea of that is to generally _prevent_ clients from requesting things outside that part of the file system. Which obviously makes sense from a security point of view, you certainly do _not_ want anyone to be able to look through your server side file system! So why would you then want to implement a specific rule for exactly that? Do me this reads as if you want to rethink your overall setup.

Comment: I want to keep the codes out of public access (public_html), is this a good way?

Comment: No, this is _not_ a good way to protect something: whether such data is stored inside the public_html folder or outside is completely irrelevant if you then go and explicitly allow access to it anyway.

Comment: What you want to keep outside of that folder is things like secrets, configurations. But then you don't rewrite or redirect to those, but you include those in your application logic.